# During crossfading MediaPlayer player pauses for while on some devices mostly on Oreo and Pie

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, fadein, fadeout, pause

I want crossfading effect when one song is about to end and other starts.I have used below code for crossFading between audio and it works fine on most of the devices but it is not working on some samsung devices running on Oreo and one plus 6. Their is very small pause as soon as second media player starts playing next song. Thanks in advance.

```
private void crossFade() {
    fadeOut(musicPlayer, CROSSFADE_DURATION);
    fadeIn(musicPlayer2, CROSSFADE_DURATION);
}

public void fadeOut(final MediaPlayer _player, final int duration) {
    final float deviceVolume = getDeviceVolume();
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        private float time = duration;
        private float volume = 0.0f;

        @Override
        public void run() {               
            // can call h again after work!
            time -= 100;
            volume = (deviceVolume * time) / duration;
            _player.setVolume(volume, volume);
            if (time > 0)
                h.postDelayed(this, 100);
            else {
                _player.stop();
                _player.release();
            }
        }
    }, 100); // delay (takes millis)


}

public void fadeIn(final MediaPlayer _player, final int duration) {
    final float deviceVolume = getDeviceVolume();
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        private float time = 0.0f;
        private float volume = 0.0f;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!_player.isPlaying())
                _player.start();
            // can call h again after work!
            time += 100;
            volume = (deviceVolume * time) / duration;
            _player.setVolume(volume, volume);
            if (time < duration)
                h.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }, 100); // delay (takes millis)

}
```

Comment: I would delay the call to `_player.stop`/`_player.release()` by a few seconds, just to see if that was associated with the "pause". For instance, you could just do `if (time > -3000)`, for a 3 second delay. Otherwise, your description of where the "pause" occurs is a little confusing: You said it was right before the 2nd player starts, but both players start at essentially the same time, here.

Comment: @greeble31 thanks for your reply. The first player is already started i(!_player.isPlaying()) _player.start(); this is added by mistake in fadeOut function and I removed it now but that doesn't affect. First player starts fade out when crossfading started and at the same time the second player starts with fadeIn. But as soon as second player is started the pause happens. So delaying the stop()/release won't solve this issue. I could not find any solution for that.

Comment: Ah, OK, so you're saying the first player skips a beat when the second player is starting. Hate to say this, but since `musicPlayer2` has obviously already been `prepared()`, you're probably out of luck. It must be some `MediaPlayer` implementation issue on these specific devices, and it's outside your control. If you really want to fix it, use `MediaCodec` to decode your audio files, mix the streams yourself, and send the data to an `AudioTrack`.

Comment: @greeble31 yes you are right its MediaPlayer's issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue by my own. Actualy MediaPlayer has this issue and its been reported to google since long ago but still not resolved(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36931073) so we can do nothing about it. So I used Exoplayer for playing audio and it works very smoothly without any pause.